# Why different value of arguments inside and outside foo function

Tags: javascript

In this following code I don't understand why arguments[0] prints 3  inside foo function, solution of this problem just gives hint:

> You need to check whether arguments exists in DOM or not

Obviously arguments is inside `DOM`. Or am I missing something?

```js
var arguments = [1, 2, 3];
var arr = () => arguments[2];
arr()
console.log(arr()); // understandable it prints 3
console.log(arguments[0]);// understandable it prints 1

function foo(n) {
console.log(arguments[0]); // do not understand why it prints 3
   var f = () => arguments[0] + n; 
   return f();
}
console.log(arguments[0]); // understandable it prints 1
foo(3);
```

Comment: Arguments refers to the list of arguments inside a function scope. Inside foo() arguments[0] refers to n, not to the globally declared arguments array. Lesson: dont use reserved keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arguments` has a special meaning in some circumstances: it refers to the *arguments passed to the closest ancestor `function`*. For this reason, it's a good idea to never define variables named `arguments` to avoid confusion. Try it:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const someFn = () => arr[2];
someFn()
console.log(someFn());
console.log(arr[0]);

function foo(n) {
  console.log(arr[0]);
  const f = () => arr[0] + n;
  return f();
}
foo(3);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

and the reason behind each log should be clear as day, since there now isn't any funny business going on.

The problem with your original code is, when you do:

```
function foo(n) {
  console.log(arguments[0]); // do not understand why it prints 3
```

The nearest enclosing (non-arrow) `function` that the `arguments` refers to is the `foo` function, and all arguments are collected into an array-like object and put into an `arguments` identifier. The above snippet is similar to doing:

```
function foo(n) {
  const theArgs = [n]; // collect all arguments into an array-like object
  console.log(theArgs[0]); // do not understand why it prints 3
```

And since the call of `foo` was `foo(3)`, `theArgs` is `[3]`, so `theArgs[0]` contains `3`.

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` is a special keyword in Javascript. `arguments` is an Array-like object accessible inside **non-arrow** functions that contains the values of the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) passed to that function.

It has a different meaning only in the scope of that function.

Even when you do not pass any parameters, the object **exists**.

```js
let arguments = [0,1,2,3];
function func1() {
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

//Arrow functions do not have special arguments object
let func2 = () =>{
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

func1(1, 2, 3);
func2(1,2,3);
```

An arrow function does not have its own `arguments` object. So here when referring to `arguments` you refer to the `arguments` defined outside it.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `argument` in method is your argument of method. Simply change the name:

```js
        var arguments1 = [1, 2, 3];
        var arr = () => arguments1[2];
        arr()
        console.log(arr()); // understandable it prints 3
        console.log(arguments1[0]);// understandable it prints 1

        function foo(n) {
            debugger
            console.log(arguments1[0]); // do not understand why it prints 3
            var f = () => arguments1[0] + n;
            return f();
        }
        console.log(arguments1[0]); // understandable it prints 1
        foo(3)
```